# Prometheus honor_labels - how to make it apply to the "internal" metrics like scrape_samples_scraped?

Tags: prometheus

My architecture involves multiple applications sending their metrics to a centralized application, which exposes them for Prometheus to scrape.

I specify `honor_labels` in my `prometheus.yml`. The metrics set the `job` label and this is reflected in the metrics themselves, but not in the `internal` metrics like `scrape_samples_scraped`. Is this even possible?

I'd like to be able to attribute sample volume to a source application. e.g.

```
scrape_samples_scraped{instance="Exporter",job="ApplicationA"}  1456323
scrape_samples_scraped{instance="Exporter",job="ApplicationB"}  32019928
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

No, the special scrape metrics always have the target labels as their labels. I'd suggest having Prometheus scrape the applications directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brian - direct scraping isn't an option here, we're using Prometheus in a central environment to be the metrics hub for many network segregated satellite environments. I'll need to get the exporter to compute and record the counts separately.